# how to destroy a page in C# xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm trying to destroy a page when the user comes out of the page.
My app works like this:

1. loginpage
2. HomePage
3. takePhotosPage

So, what I want is that when the user comes back from takePhotosPage to HomePage, takePhotosPage destroys itself.

It is simple but I don't find any solution.

I use this code to come back to homepage

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Xamarin views do not implement "Dispose". Xamarin is responsible for managing their lifetime. What is your underlying goal? Can you do whatever you seek to do in page's `public override void OnDisappearing()`?

Comment: the GC should clean it up for you if it is no longer being referenced